# Do polynomial functions in [0,1] with coefficients in [0,1] and with sum 1 give a complete lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

Let us take the set $F$ of all functions from $[0,1]$ to reals of the form:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n \in N} q_n x^n$$
such that:

- $0 \le q_n \le 1$ for all naturals $n$
- $\sum_{n \in N} q_n$ = 1
- the set $\{n | q_n >0\}$ is at most countable

Let us define the ordering relations $\sqsubseteq$ over $F$ such that $f \sqsubseteq f'$ if and only if $f(x) \le f'(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

My conjecture is that this is a complete lattice, but I was unable to prove this. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does $N$ denote the natural numbers or some arbitrary set?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the definition of a complete lattice.

Comment: Also, the set of all natural numbers is already countable, so the third "dot" is trivially satisfied. Did you mean: finite?

Comment: @Feanor That's exactly the source of my confusion. Especially, since the title mentions polynomials...

Answer (score 4):

The set $F$ you define is not a complete lattice.

Consider the set $A = \{1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots\}$. I claim that $A$ does not have an infimum in $F$. For suppose $f(x) = \sum_n q_n x^n$ is such infimum.

For any $m$ you have $f(x) \leq x^m$ for all $x$. In particular, for any $n,m$ you have $q_nx^n \leq x^m$, and if you take $m > n$ and $x$ small enough, you find that $q_n$ has to be $0$. But this is true for all $n$, so $f(x) = 0$, identically. This contradicts the condition $\sum_n q_n = 1$.

(I'm not sure what happens if you drop the assumption that $\sum_n q_n = 1$. Perhaps this leads to a complete lattice.)

Comment: Feanor's counterexample shows my conjecture is wrong. Thanks for you effort and reply. What happens if I add to F the constants 0 and 1, namely I consider $F \cup \{0,1\}$? Thnaks!

Comment: I thought the constant $1$ is already there ($1 = x^0$). As for $0$, it won't help much: just take $A = \{\alpha x^n + \beta \ | \ n \in N\}$ for arbitrary $\alpha,\beta > 0$ with $\alpha + \beta = 1$.

Comment: You are right!. But let me insist with my challenge (apologize). Assume we consider $N \cup \lambda$ instead of $N$, where $\lambda$ is such that $x^{\lambda}$ = 0 for all $0 < x < 1$. Assume also that the functions are defined in $(0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$. In this way the constant $\beta$ is $(1-\beta) x^{\lambda} + \beta x^0$. I believe the picture is now different. Thanks!

Comment: Right now, it seems to me that the answer is still "no". Here is why: Consider two functions $f,g \in F$ such that it is not the case that $f \leq g$ not $g \leq f$. Let $h$ be their infimum, in the sense of lattices. In all except for finitely many points you have $h(x) < f(x),g(x)$ (strictly), so I think you can modify $h$ slightly to get another function $h'$ which is still smaller than $f,g$, but not comparable to $h$.